# 2D array in by reference

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, char

I have this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//definições de constantes usadas para agilizar a implementação.
#define MINA  'M'
#define SUB  'S'
#define JOG  'U'
#define CC  'I'

//Função que inicializa posição do jogador.
void posjog(char **mesa,int lin, int col){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand() % 2;
    int j = rand() % 2;
    if(i==1){
        i = lin;
    }
    if(j==1){
        j = col;
    }
    mesa[i][j] = JOG;
}

//Função que inicializa a matriz vazia.
void arfill(char **mesa,int lin, int col){
    for(int i=0;i<=lin;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=col;j++){
            mesa[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
}

void show(char **mesa,int lin,int col){
    for(int i=0;i<=lin;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=col;j++){
                printf("%c",mesa[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int main(void) {
    char campo[9][9]; //matriz de jogo
    arfill(campo,9,9);
    posjog(campo,9,9);
    show(campo,9,9);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My code always crashes, i dunno why.
Can some of you please help me with this?
I have some Warnings on the Eclipse too...
"passing argument 1 of 'arfill' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]"
"expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[9]'"

Comment: Have you used debugger to check which line it crashes. Also, what sort of problem? Does it not compile/build? If it builds, use debugger to find out which line it starts having issues.

Comment: `void func(int lin, int col, char mesa[lin][col])` and `i<=lin`,`j<=col` --> `i<lin`,`j<col`

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and that warning tells you everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexing starts from 0 and ends in size of array - 1.

So, this

```
for(int i=0;i<=lin;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=col;j++){
```

will go from 0 to 9 for an array of size 9x9, thus it will go out of bounds.

Similarly the rest of the code has similar problems.

---

You should definitely enable the warning of your compiler (`-Wall` flag would suffice for a start). Warnings are good to be treated like errors by us. Here is what I got:

```
../main.c: In function ‘main’:
../main.c:45:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘arfill’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:26:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[9]’
../main.c:46:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘posjog’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:12:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[9]’
../main.c:47:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘show’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
../main.c:34:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[9]’
Finished building: ../main.c
```

---

So one way to deal with this is to use `define` for the sizes of the matrix. Then your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//definições de constantes usadas para agilizar a implementação.
#define MINA  'M'
#define SUB  'S'
#define JOG  'U'
#define CC  'I'

#define N 9
#define M 9

//Função que inicializa posição do jogador.
void posjog(char mesa[N][M]) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i = rand() % 2;
  int j = rand() % 2;
  if (i == 1) {
    i = N;
  }
  if (j == 1) {
    j = M;
  }
  // if i and j have the value of N and M, this will go out of bounds
  // mesa[i][j] = JOG;   <---- modify this
}

//Função que inicializa a matriz vazia.
void arfill(char mesa[N][M]) {
  // Replaces <= with < in both for loops
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      mesa[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }
}

void show(char mesa[N][M]) {
  // Replaces <= with < in both for loops
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      printf("%c", mesa[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void) {
  char campo[N][M];  //matriz de jogo
  arfill(campo);
  posjog(campo);
  show(campo);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Of course you could dynamically allocate the memory for the array, which would get rid of the `define`. In that case don't forget to de-allocate your memory.